# why would a p value be > .05 when the mean is 1.6?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

[image]

So I don't understand this explanation. How do they know that the value of u = 1.6 is inside the 95% confidence interval? I know that a z score of 1.6 would be inside it but its just  value for u. I'm looking at the section for this problem and the graphs but i don't see why this is true.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what the 95% confidence is about. It is in the statement "$\mu$ is between 1.2 and 2". It is not a statement about the z-score (although z-scores are used in order to find what the confidence interval is).

So the statement is true.

Comment: ok i get why the statement is true, but why is the p value greater than .05?

Comment: @2316354654 when the interval was  constructed from the data, the conclusion was "the mean is in this interval with 95% probability". Conversely, if this data is used to test a null, that is, the answer to the question, "what are the chances this set of data would have been drawn mu really is outside of (1.2,2)" is less than 5% and "... if mu is within this interval, is greater than 5%". That's exactly the question that p value encapsulates.